# What is my best ram configuration given my available ram?

Tags: motherboard, memory

I have a **TRX40 AORUS PRO WIFI** motherboard - and 6 sticks of ram all from the same manufacturer - **G.Skill TridentZ RGB** with 2x32GB and 4x8GB available memory.

To avoid any confusion, let me define the ram slots with numbers from 1-8

[image]

My question is - where should I install the ram to maximize available memory and speed?

**Edit**
I found a table in manual and it appears that one can install 6 modules in the slots as indicated in the table below.

So then the question simplifies to where should the 2x32G Ram vs 4x8G Ram should go, i.e.: what number slots below? Do you put the 2x32G next to each other or across the CPU?

[image]

Comment: mas availible ram is to install it all

Comment: Do not mix different **model numbers** of memory in the same channel, and ideally don't mix different models of memory in the same board at all. 2x32GB is more RAM than 4x8GB and those 2x32GB sticks might run faster on their own than if you installed all of the sticks. The board is quad channel though, so depending on the workload you might find those 4x8GB sticks in quad channel could be faster than the 2x32GB in dual channel. The only way to know is to benchmark the different configurations and decide what provides the best balance of speed and capacity for you.

Comment: the *don't mix ram* is overrated; that idea no longer is true with modern ram if it was then XMP and memory overclocking would not work (and it does).  All *modern* RAM follows specification and they will alter clock and timing to a common value to work... you would only be giving up that speed which the faster ram could've run at but had to down clock to to work with other ram.  so mixing ram between GSkill, crucial, samsung means almost nothing today.  Also: https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-memory/truth-about-memory-manufacturers

Comment: "they will alter clock and timing to a common value to work" -- And that might not be the "best" configuration in the end. You need to read my comment in the context of the question being asked. Mixing RAM in this case is probably not the right advice. OP needs to explain what "best" means to them and ideally tell us the models of the RAM sticks too.

Comment: @Romen I added some more info - but I do not know too much about this stuff.

Comment: pairs of ram split up on the A1/A2 or B1/B2 socket of the same channel.  quad channel A,B,C,D so the **2**x32gb would go on A1&A2, or B1&B2, or C1&C2.  you populate channel A first, then B, then C, then D.  D will be open for you because you are short 2 dimms out of a total of 8.  The smaller capacity 8gb dimms what channel they go on will have no affect.

Comment: Disregard the last comment.  According to the mobo manual for 6 dimms you leave channel C1 and A1 open.  pairs of ram typically split up on the same channel, such as disregard the last comment.  the **2x32gb** would go on (A1 and A2) or (B1 or B2) and so on.  According to the chart for your 6 dimm setup would be channels B and D, but it likely would not matter you will find out once installed if the mobo passes POST or if it beeps in error because of ram misconfiguration.  you won't hurt anything if you install it wrong.

Comment: Edit your existing answer instead of posting the answer as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/TRX40-AORUS-PRO-WIFI-rev-10#kf

**specifications:**

- 8 x DDR4 DIMM sockets supporting up to 256 GB (32 GB single DIMM capacity) of system memory
- Quad Channel memory architecture
- Support for DDR4 4400(O.C.) / 4266(O.C.) / 4133(O.C.) / 4000(O.C.) / 3866(O.C.) / 3733(O.C.) / 3600(O.C.) / 3466(O.C.) / 3400(O.C.) / 3333(O.C.) / 3300(O.C.) / 3200 / 2933 / 2667 / 2400 / 2133 MHz memory modules
- Support for ECC Un-buffered DIMM 1Rx8/2Rx8 memory modules
- Support for non-ECC Un-buffered DIMM 1Rx8/2Rx8/1Rx16 memory modules
- Support for Extreme Memory Profile (XMP) memory modules

because it is quad channel you want to populate all 4 channels for maximum performance possible; not populating all 4 channels will still work just not as fast as it could possibly be.

RAM is installed in pairs (i forget that specific reason, its not the "dual data rate DDR" thing though).  So 2 x 4channels = 8 total slots.  Each slot at most a 32gb dimm,  a 64gb dimm will not work.  so 32 x 8 = 256gb = max ram supported = maximum performance in terms of both speed and memory capacity.  If you did 8x8gb DIMMS for 64gb total ram the performance would be the same just not the capacity (for the same memory speeds).

Maximum performance would be 8x32gb of DDR4 4400, installed in all 8 DIMM slots, followed by DDR4-4266, and so on.

And unbufferred non-ECC ram would be fastest, which is the typical consumer ram; ECC ram (for servers) would technically be slower; if interested a web search on non-ECC vs ECC should answer that in technical terms if you're interested.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer OP's question. You ignored the RAM that they said they already have and they were asking what configuration to install it. They are not purchasing RAM. We really need more info to answer the question at this point.

Comment: can you read?  *because it is quad channel you want to populate all 4 channels for maximum performance possible; not populating all 4 channels will still work just not as fast as it could possibly be.*

Comment: not to mention his little ram configuration table he posted, i wonder where he learned to get that from?  obviously could not have been my link to the motherboard manual having that on page 12, because nothing i explained answered his question

Comment: Your answer reads more like a suggestion to buy 8x32GB 4400 MHz sticks. A huge part of your answer is irrelevant to the question and suggesting ECC RAM and all sorts of information that is totally distracting. The one quote you've pointed out hits the point of the question but you didn't elaborate on *that* enough to help OP. Just linking their motherboard manual is evidently not helpful to OP; They want to know specifically which sticks go in which slots so that is the information that I would upvote as an actual answer to the question.